# jQuery bxslider in tabbed divs

Tags: jquery, bxslider

If anyone has come accross this problem and solved it then help would be great.

I have 3 sliders on a page, not a problem and working fine until i drop each one into a jQuery tabbed content container. Then the first one runs as it should but when I change the tab to hide the first div with the working slider in I only get the prev/next arrows and the slide number count, but the slides li's are hidden.

Any help would be fab.

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 1):

The height of `bx-viewport` needs to be reset. Or as Korhan said, you can fix it by setting this parameter manually on `jquery.bxslider.css` file. Setting this parameter solved my problem, with seems to be the same.

This problem is difficult to understand, not only because it is (probably) a bug, but because you will need also to verify others DOM's manipulation that you are doing and, until now, there is not a official response over this question. Take long-time look at the div's names and theirs Class' or Id's, check if you have a bx-viewport's issue and every thing should work normally.

> **Update-1**
>
> > Other way to solve this problem is to attach an **onclick Event** in your **nav** and then **fire** the **bxslider** on user's click.
> >
> > You could do this approach attaching one id by one, or creating something similar to a regex to fit it. After that, when the event fires you will need to get some id of content tab. Having this specific id, you can search for the correct 'bxslider's id inside of it. You can do this by using Jquery **find** function. At this point you can **call the bxslider  constructor**.

This should work in modern browser, so again, take a long-time look at IE issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. when I look at the firebug,  I realized *bx-viewport" height is 0px for each slider in tabs. Just give it static height in css and solve this problem, all sliders are visible in tabs.